# Opening SQLite3 as READONLY with PDO?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

The SQLite3 Class has an option like this.

```
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db', SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
```

In PDO you would simply open with:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db');
```

My question is however, is there a way to open a database with PDO, in READONLY mode?

Answer (score 6):

This will become possible with the release of PHP 7.3 (estimated for release in late 2018).

The syntax is as follows:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:mysqlitedb.db', null, null, [PDO::SQLITE_ATTR_OPEN_FLAGS => PDO::SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY]);
```

[Upstream commit](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/ed2f6510da7c68b5690c60344cbb9fe73241592a)

Comment: This is indeed available since PHP 7.3 (tested right now with PHP 7.3.3)

Comment: It will return an "attempt to write a readonly database" error if you try to write something in the database.

However, it does not mean somebody else can write into the database at the same time. It still locks the database. For instance if you try to use sqlite3 in command line on the same database at the same time, and attempt to write something, you will get an "Error: database is locked" error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible with pdo (yet?).
The pdo_sqlite driver of php 5.3 uses [sqlite3_open()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html) in `pdo_sqlite_handle_factory()` but you need sqlite3_open_v2() to pass the read only flag.

edit:
But a patch would be fairly easy. Take a look at `pdo_mysql_handle_factory()` in ext/pdo_mysql/mysql_driver.c and how it uses `struct pdo_data_src_parser vars[]` to parse the dns string.