# Best way to access sqlite database in read mode using php

Tags: php, sqlite

Couple questions. Whats the best way to access a live .db file using sqlite to just read data?

Secondly

```
$url = "data.db";

try

{

$db = new PDO('sqlite:"$url"');

...
```

How can I correct this syntax so I can set the database url as a variable? If I must use a different method other than PDO because of question 1 please set it out with a variable for database url.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shamelessly taken from [Opening SQLite3 as READONLY with PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1352270/opening-sqlite3-as-readonly-with-pdo):

Instead of PDO, try the SQLite3 library:

```
$db = new SQLite3($url, SQLITE3_OPEN_READONLY);
```

For more details, refer to PHP's doc:

http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.open.php

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found.

EDIT: Needed to enable it. Fixed