# Option readonly of SQLite in PDO

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I know that the readonly option does not exist in the PDO.

I have a database, accessible only in read mode(chmod for file read only).
I need only perform SELECT and SELECT COUNT queries.

Is it safe to such use?

I am afraid that SQLite at some point want to write some logs, logs, etc.
And then I'll have to catch this type of situation. It is not easy in a large application.

Or performing SELECT and SELECT COUNT queries excluded any attempt to change the file?

Comment: Starting from PHP 7.3, it is possible to [open SQLite in readonly mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46180528).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have readonly access to your DB, those types of queries (select) wont bring you trouble, unless you try to insert, update, delete, or alter the schema.

Just **consider** that sqlite [fits](https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html) specially well for small projects rather than large ones. For large projects sqlite is considered not a good practice.